# If the estimated propensity scores repeat themselves for certain units, how would that affect an Inverse Weighted Scoring Estimator?

Tags: experiment-design, causality, propensity-scores

Suppose I have $N$ units in an observational study with treatment and control and I just computed the propensity scores for each. If I find that the propensity scores are clustered, ie, the first 10 units share the same propensity score, then the second five share the same propensity score, etc, what analysis can I draw here and how would this affect things if I use an Inverse Weighted Propensity Score regression?

For example, If I have $N=50$ units, and I find that the estimated propensity scores are:

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
  \hline
 \text{Units}& \text{Propensity Score} \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.30 \\ 
  2 & 0.30 \\ 
  3 & 0.30 \\ 
  4 & 0.30 \\ 
  5 & 0.30 \\ 
  6 & 0.30 \\ 
  7 & 0.30 \\ 
  8 & 0.30 \\ 
  9 & 0.30 \\ 
  10 & 0.30 \\ 
  11 & 0.25 \\ 
  12 & 0.25 \\ 
  13 & 0.25 \\ 
  14 & 0.25 \\ 
  15 & 0.25 \\ 
  16 & 0.25 \\ 
  17 & 0.25 \\ 
  18 & 0.25 \\ 
  19 & 0.25 \\ 
  20 & 0.25 \\ 
  21 & 0.97 \\ 
  22 & 0.97 \\ 
  23 & 0.97 \\ 
  24 & 0.97 \\ 
  25 & 0.97 \\ 
  26 & 0.97 \\ 
  27 & 0.97 \\ 
  28 & 0.97 \\ 
  29 & 0.97 \\ 
  30 & 0.97 \\ 
  31 & 0.66 \\ 
  32 & 0.66 \\ 
  33 & 0.66 \\ 
  34 & 0.66 \\ 
  35 & 0.66 \\ 
  36 & 0.66 \\ 
  37 & 0.66 \\ 
  38 & 0.66 \\ 
  39 & 0.66 \\ 
  40 & 0.66 \\ 
  41 & 0.13 \\ 
  42 & 0.13 \\ 
  43 & 0.13 \\ 
  44 & 0.13 \\ 
  45 & 0.13 \\ 
  46 & 0.13 \\ 
  47 & 0.13 \\ 
  48 & 0.13 \\ 
  49 & 0.13 \\ 
  50 & 0.13 \\ 
   \hline
\end{array}
$$

Then it is that the first 10 units share $0.3$ as a propensity score, the next 10 units share $0.25$ as a propensity score, and so forth.

My question is, in this case how would this affect my inverse propensity score weighted estimator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't at all. This is what you would expect with a stratified randomized control trial, and IPTW estimators are valid for those.